# package-lock.json is not working in heroku

Tags: javascript, npm, package-lock.json

İ made a discord bot and İ want it working 24/7.

Heroku logs:

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

My package-lock.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello-express",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "abs": {
      "version": "1.3.14",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/abs/-/abs-1.3.14.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PrS26IzwKLWwuURpiKl8wRmJ2KdR/azaVrLEBWG/TALwT20Y7qjtYp1qcMLHA4206hBHY5phv3w4pjf9NPv4Vw==",
      "requires": {
        "ul": "^5.0.0"
      }
    },
    "ansi-styles": {
      "version": "3.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-3.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-VT0ZI6kZRdTh8YyJw3SMbYm/u+NqfsAxEpWO0Pf9sq8/e94WxxOpPKx9FR1FlyCtOVDNOQ+8ntlqFxiRc+r5qA==",
      "requires": {
        "color-convert": "^1.9.0"
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json` and running `npm install`? That's all what your error says

Comment: Heroku dont have console
( maybe have console ? )

Comment: `heroku run bash` to get a bash console

Comment: Where do I write the code you said